# what is the most efficient way of getting digit sum?

Tags: python, math

I have to find the digit sum until its in single digit.
if input is -9999 then output should be -9
 `(-(9+9+9+9))==-9)`

if input is 9012 then output should be 3 `(+(9+0+1+2)==1+2==3))`

ps: i have solved this but the negative inputs are giving wrong output.I am using the division by 9 property(you can google it) in order to get o(1) solution

my code:

```py
def digSum(n): 
    if (n == 0): 
        return 0
    if (n % 9 == 0): 
        return 9
    else: 
        (n % 9)
```

Comment: I don't quite follow the logic here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica If a number n is divisible by 9, then the sum of its digit until sum becomes single digit is always 9. For example,
Let, n = 2880
Sum of digits = 2 + 8 + 8 = 18: 18 = 1 + 8 = 9

A number can be of the form 9x or 9x + k. For the first case, answer is always 9. For the second case, and is always k.

Comment: … Or the sign *is* part of the digits, then the result is -9 + 9 + 9 + 9 => 18 => 1 + 8 => 9 and not -9.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thats why i have provided both positive and negative example to avoid the confusion about sign

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214400/discussion-between-sk07-and-jorg-w-mittag).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a simple recursion should help, add this to your code

```py
if n < 0:
  return - digSum(abs(n))
```

Comment: its still not giving the output of -9 when input is -99999

Comment: ur complete code ?

Comment: @it works fine . error is on other part.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close, but you need to check to see if the input is a negative number BEFORE you evaluate if it modulates 9 or not. Your current code evaluates if n % 9 == 0 and returns 9, but you should add a condition to check if it's negative and n % 9 first, otherwise it will always return a positive number.

Modify your code to be this:

```
def digSum(n):

    if (n == 0):
        return 0
    if (n % 9 == 0 and n < 0):
        return -9
    if (n % 9 == 0):
        return 9
    else:
        (n % 9)
```